# Solidity: return values in for cycle

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to return multiple values inside a for cycle? I mean, without knowing the number of output (it will be dynamically increased every time an array will be filled), is it possible to represent every element of that array as output of a function?

Something like this

```
function getList() view public returns (string, address) {

    for (uint i = 0; i < arrayOfStringValues.length; i++){

        return (arrayOfStringValues[i], arrayOfAddressValues[i]);}
}
```

I tried to do this, but the function returns only the first "couple".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **No.**
>
> A function returns a result **once**. It cannot loop over all your array, and returns a tuple at each iteration.

You can return a dynamic sized array to an external function call ( contract exterior : e.g web3 / other contract ).

In **theory** it can work like this :

```
function getList() external returns (string[], address[]) {

        return (arrayOfStringValues[], arrayOfAddressValues[]);
}
```

**But you would have an error** as you can't return `string[]` yet in solidity.
so if you can find a way to use `bytes32` instead of string, it should work.

Note : If you need to call this external function **from inside your contract** you can use `this.getList()` as it will make it look as an external call.

**EDIT :** i just saw that the latest solidity release `0.4.22` opens the possibility to return `string[]` and `bytes32[]` in functions without the external modifier. ( someone verify this please )

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

A function returns a result **once**. It cannot loop over all your array, and returns a tuple at each iteration.